No matching 'FB_Init' method found for instantiation of FbPowerPlantControl
when i run a program i receive the below massage.
"No matching 'FB_Init' method found for instantiation of FbPowerPlantControl. Specified 'FB_Init' method requires exactly 2 inputs. Check syntax 'FbPowerPlantControl_01 : FbPowerPlantControl(POINTER TO I_Data_PPC_Controls,ARRAY [1..1] OF __SYSTEM.__ARRAY__DIM__INFO)'"
how to remove this error
i need to remove above error
